# Slow Time To First Byte (TTFB)

Tags: php, apache, performance, ssl, time-to-first-byte

My website has a really long TTFB, about 10-20 seconds.
Here are the results from webpagetest: https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191231_XT_1c7004d39484c32e8e2493c4b4bb75c4/2/details/

The web bytecheck says that the very long task is SSL. But the SSL certificate (letsencrypt) seems to be ok (ssllabs.com/ssltest gives an A grade).

Also I think it is not a code issue, because if I create a new html static page that only contains the word "hello", it also takes several seconds to load.
The server doesn't seem to be overload either, the command htop shows a very low CPU and RAM usage.

So, any idea what can be slowing the website?

Comment: Maybe the network is very loaded in on your hosting server?
Try to deploy on another hosting and check if it is so.

Comment: How can I check if the network is very loaded? But I don't think so, the provider is Hetzner, and my server is dedicated.

Comment: Find out what's happening on the server side with logging.

Comment: what kind of logging?